# How can I display text or image in a div with an image in it's content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div tag used for a banner so I'm setting it's content to be an image. However, I would like to display some text and glyphicons inside of that div. I'm was trying to use a Bootstrap Grid to lay it out but I can't get anything to display inside the div. I've tried just putting in some simple text without any luck.

What is the proper way to do something like that?

This is what I've tried. The image shows up but none of the text.

```
div.banner {
    content: url('../Images/banner.jpg');
    background-color: #A5B7C7;
}​

<div class="banner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> something goes here</div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> something else</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JacobGray, the text should not show, because the `content` property replaces the content. Check my answer.

Comment: @Dekel I completely missed that xD +1

Comment: @JacobGray yeah, it's a tricky one. You can upvote my answer if you like ;)

Comment: @Caverman - if you decided to accept the `background` answer - I think it makes more sense that you choose the answer by paolobasso as it was the first one.

Comment: Didn't know his was first. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-image` insted of `content`

Answer (score 2):

The `content` property will replace the content of the element. Instead - you can use the `:before` pseudo-class (or switch from `content` to `background-iamge`):

```css
div.banner {
    background-color: #A5B7C7;
}
div.banner:before {
    content: url('https://dummyimage.com/150x100/263cb5/ffffff');  
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> something goes here</div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> something else</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the css property content, use the property background like:

```
div.banner {
    background: url('../Images/banner.jpg');
}​
```

Comment: This answer already exists, there is no need for duplication.

Answer (score 0):

`content` will not allow text to be placed over it by default. You would have to add more css. Please change content to `background-image`

```
  .banner {
        background-image: url('../Images/banner.jpg');
        background-color: #A5B7C7;
    }​

<div class="banner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> something goes here</div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> something else</div>
    </div>
</div>
```